# How to write a query to get the custom output as a result using AZURE KQL?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, kql

**Issue what we are facing:**
We are currently facing an exception which blocks our flow. We are trying to understand why this issue is occurring
too many times using log analytics in azure. Using this approach its a time taking and finally there is no conclusion.

We heard that the same can achieve using KQL. I am a beginner in this KQL and felt that its not a straight forward to get the following expected output.

I need your help to get the expected output using AZURE KQL this way we can find and take a quick decision.

**Expected Output:**
Exception
-Error Message
-Failed at which method
-Failed in which page
-Failed at which line
-In Which Module
-Type of Exception
-At what time
-Before and after this exception
-Get count of this exception how many times it occured.

Comment: The question is not clear. Please edit your question, and add sample input (in datatable format), the expected output, the query you wrote, and details on why your query doesn't work (you said it produces an error, please provide details).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please know that it is the same Kusto Query Language (KQL) that powers querying Log Analytics on Azure. So your ask of "using KQL instead of Log Analytics" is pretty confusing.

Log Analytics is the primary tool in the Azure portal for editing log queries and interactively analyzing their results. It also allows you to write simple queries without directly working with the query language. If you haven't used Log Analytics before, start with the [Log Analytics Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/log-analytics-tutorial) so you understand the tool that you'll use with the other tutorials and samples.

As far as KQL is concerned, here are some great resources that can help you get started:

- [Tutorial: Use Kusto queries in Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tutorial?pivots=azuremonitor)
- [Samples queries for Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/samples?pivots=azuremonitor)
- [Kusto Query Language (KQL) from Scratch](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/kusto-query-language-kql-from-scratch)